# The hadoop job always UNASSIGNED on local Yarn

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I set up the local yarn on my laptop. After I submitted the job, the job stuck in UNASSIGNED. I don't know why and which log file I can check ?

Comment: have yo checked the logs ?

Comment: Hi Mostafa,  may i know which log file I have to check. Yarn's log ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. That is I miss-used

`<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
 <value>/tmp/hadoop-yarn/aggrelogs</value>
</property>`